# c++ how to point to a member of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

Wondering how to assign a pointer to an array member:

```
struct foo {
    int INT;
}

int main() {
    foo bar[10];
    foo *baz;
    baz = bar[5];
}
```

This does not work, but I am wondering what would.
Thank you much for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You want to do `baz = &bar[5];`. `bar[5]` Refers to the 6th `foo` object instance itself, so just take the address (with the `&` operator) to assign to the pointer, same as any other situation;

Alternatively, you can also do `baz = (bar + 5);` since here `bar` used without a number is a pointer to the first element and +5 gives the 6th element.

Comment: Just to be clear: Unary `&` is the operator that gets the address of (pointer to) a given object.

Comment: Or `5 + bar` as weird obfuscation technique!